# Ways to find headstone names in Mexican cemeteries?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, cemeteries, mexico

I am a complete newbie.

I've heard there are compilations and other documentation of headstones, foot-stones, etc. from cemeteries in various countries.

Is there such a compilation for Mexico?

I am most interested in burials during the last 150 or 200 years in various places in Mexico.

FindaGrave.com is the type of search engine I was hoping to find (thanks to bgwiehle). Are there other such compliations?

Also, what search strategies might one try in using these databases  to find cemetery transcriptions from Mexico from this period?

Comment: This question is rather broad and does not show that any research has been done. FindaGrave.com has 805 Mexican cemeteries, BillionGraves.com has at least 100. Even Wikipedia has a category https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cemeteries_in_Mexico. If you are looking for transcription projects or resources other than the previous sites, you should at least specify a state.

Comment: You also may find this page helpful: https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Mexico_Cemeteries

Comment: @bgwiehle I think you should combine your two comments into an answer.

Comment: The question could be re-worked and answered with effective *search strategies* for finding cemetery transcriptions for Mexico, instead of simply listing links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a newbie, the biggest disadvantages are not knowing where to look for answers and asking simplistic questions. However, "Google is your friend."

That is, just **googling** the words [mexico cemetery index](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mexico%20cemetery%20index&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=OQjCVvPNKYHK-QHBn6OQCw), or [mexico cemetery transcription](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mexico%20cemetery%20transcription&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iE7CVsz2GIHn-QH5vYOYDA), returns as the first hit:

[Mexico Cemeteries](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Mexico_Cemeteries) (**FamilySearch Wiki**), which gives an overview of what can be expected from cemetery records in Mexico, and links to state resources.

Additional google hits lead to
[Mexico Cemetery Records](http://www.interment.net/mexico/index.htm) at **interment.net**
and
**Find-a-Grave** as a site with Mexican cemeteries (better link to [Mexican cemeteries](http://findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=csr&CScn=&CScntry=45&CSst=0))
and
some cemetery pages at [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/), which can lead to the [Category:Cemeteries in Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cemeteries_in_Mexico) page

---

Say you're not quite as much of a newbie anymore, and you know about [Cyndi's List](http://www.cyndislist.com/), "a categorized & cross-referenced index to genealogical resources on the Internet."

Use the category list to find [Mexico](http://www.cyndislist.com/mexico/) and see that there is a [Cemeteries & Funeral Homes](http://www.cyndislist.com/mexico/cemeteries/) sub-category.

Now you have a link to the 3rd major international cemetery site
**BillionGraves** - [Mexico Cemeteries](http://www.cyndislist.com/openurl/?url=357253)

---

Of course, these are general results. If you were to search with **more specific search terms**, such as the name of a particular cemetery or look for resources in a single Mexican state, you would get more relevant hits in a google search and could drill more deeply into the sites noted above. You might also find resources on genealogical society sites, or even sites for cities or companies that own cemeteries.

**Note:** Find-a-Grave, BillionGraves and Interment.net are grown through **user-submitted content**. As such, there will be gaps and errors. Often, one of the cemetery sites will have more on particular cemeteries or regions than the others.

The main cemetery sites characterized:

- [interment.net](http://interment.net/) - Free. Basic lists of names of the interred, no photos, minimal information
- [findagrave.com](http://findagrave.com/) - Free. Individual memorials can include a variety of information types (dates, places, relationship links, transcripts, grave and portrait photos, etc), also many other features. Searchable from ancestry, and familysearch
- [billiongraves.com](https://billiongraves.com/search/#) - Free, but subscription-based for additional features. Focus on photos with GPS data, but additional information and record images can be attached. Searchable from ancestry, myheritage, and familysearch